# How do i find available date ranges from date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Sql Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dP5s.jpg)

I already added bookings from my hotel room management system reservation data. I want sql query for retrieve rooms available date ranges and also i want find specific date range is available

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please provide some additional information, Sample data, and what you expect as a result set.

Comment: Where do we find availability?

Comment: i have attached image top of the question. "Sql Server" is the image

Comment: `start_date_1 =< end_date_2 and end_date_1 >= start_date_1` returns overlapping and `start_date_1 >= end_date_2 OR end_date_1 <= start_date_2` disjunct ranges. You might have to adjust `>=` to `>` depending on your ogic.

Comment: Do you have a calander table in your db and if not can you add one?

Comment: No i do not have a calendar db

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following. It's not an easy query, I'll try to explain as simple as possible.

1. Use a recursive CTE to generate dates from a specified start date to a specified end date.
2. Join each date to the different room IDs you might have in your table to create all potential available dates.
3. Determine which dates are unavailable for each room.
4. Determine which dates are available for each room by joining all potential available dates and removing unavailable ones (point 2 vs 3).
5. Determine how to group by each range (I used a `ROW_NUMBER` with a `DENSE_RANK`).
6. Display results in intervals, for each room.

Script:

```
-- Period to consider
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-06-20'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2018-09-01'

;WITH GeneratedDates AS
(
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = @StartDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, G.GeneratedDate)
    FROM
        GeneratedDates AS G
    WHERE
        G.GeneratedDate < @EndDate
),
ExistingRooms AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        RoomId
    FROM
        HotelReservation.dbo.Reservation AS R
),
UnavailableDatesByRoom AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        R.RoomID,
        UnavailableDate = G.GeneratedDate
    FROM
        HotelReservation.dbo.Reservation AS R
        INNER JOIN GeneratedDates AS G ON G.GeneratedDate BETWEEN R.CheckIn AND R.CheckOut
),
AvailableDaysByRoom AS
(
    SELECT
        AvailableDate = G.GeneratedDate,
        E.RoomID,
        DateRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.RoomID ORDER BY G.GeneratedDate ASC)
    FROM
        GeneratedDates AS G
        CROSS JOIN ExistingRooms AS E
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                'unavailable date for that room'
            FROM
                UnavailableDatesByRoom AS U
            WHERE
                U.RoomID = E.RoomID AND
                G.GeneratedDate = U.UnavailableDate)
),
AvailableDaysByRoomGroupings AS
(
    SELECT
        A.*,
        MagicRanking = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.RoomID ORDER BY DateRanking - DATEDIFF(DAY, '2010-01-01', A.AvailableDate))
    FROM
        AvailableDaysByRoom AS A
)
SELECT
    G.RoomID,
    FirstAvailableStartDate = MIN(G.AvailableDate),
    LastAvailableStartDate = MAX(G.AvailableDate)
FROM
    AvailableDaysByRoomGroupings AS G
GROUP BY
    G.RoomID,
    G.MagicRanking
ORDER BY
    G.RoomID,
    FirstAvailableStartDate
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 32000)
```